# Is there a way to write MATLAB objects to memory?

Tags: excel, matlab, oop, object, serialization

Right now I am going through a large excel database (of over 16,000) entries, and turning the entries into objects of a class I created. Because it takes so long to go through the database and create all of the objects, I was wondering if there is a way to save these objects to memory, so that rather than reconverting the database to objects every time I run the program, I could just run a conversion script once, and then just load the objects.

Thanks!

Comment: by memory, do you mean secondary memory ?

Comment: I mean like hardware memory, as in you can write to an excel file with xlswrite, but I was wondering if there is another file format you could write to that you could write objects to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you process the data into objects, the objects will be in the workspace. Then just save the object to .mat.

For example,

```
p = rand(1,10);
q = ones(10);
save('yourfile.mat','p','q')
```

Next time, just open the .mat file to get the data.

Example:

```
load('yourfile.mat')
```

Just like @Amro said read up on this: mathworks.com/help/matlab/control-save-and-load.html

Comment: since the OP is working with objects and classes, it is worth pointing to docs on object-oriented save/load operations: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/control-save-and-load.html